# How to match regular expression with a dynamic text component

Tags: regex, matlab

I need to make a regular expression match that contains a text component that comes from a variable.

The character vector contained in the variable is long and may contain characters that are operators, quantifiers, metacharacters, etc in Matlab's regular expression engine.

Is there a way to match that text component as is?

Using `strfind()` would be non-ideal because my desired match comprises of some pattern before the text component, exact match of the text component, and some pattern after. The text can be matched by itself, but matching the components before and after would be inconvenient.

An example (which doesn't necessarily fully capture the inconvenience) would be:

```
pat_b='%%\s+(?<name1>abc\d{6})\s+'; % pattern before
txt='asdf(1).qwer=[123:456,789]; zxcv;'; % text from variable
pat_a='\s+%%\s+(?<name2>\w{6})'; % pattern after
```

I tried using

```
f_txt=@()txt;
expression=[pat_b,'(??@f_txt())',pat_a];
regexp(txt_to_search,expression,'names'),
```

But couldn't get a correct match. Most likely, the result of `f_txt()` was read without escaping the special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to this situation that use the [`pattern`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pattern.html) feature:

1. Use [strfind()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) to return the location of matches in a string
2. Use [extract()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/extract.html) to return the text of the matches in a string

The `pattern` feature allows you to create complex matching requirements for strfind(), extract(), and other functions. Here is an example using simplified versions of the Question example:

```
    % a regex at start
    pat_b = 'ab\s[A-Z]';
    % exact text in the middle with random characters
    txt = '-&*\s%%8';
    % a regex at the end
    pat_a = '[a-z]{2,4}';
    
    % create a "pattern" from the three parts
    pat = regexpPattern(pat_b) + txt + regexpPattern(pat_a);
    
    % create test strings for matching
    str1 = "asdfjkl;ab C-&*\s%%8def";
    str2 = "asdfjkl;ab C-&*\s%%8wxyz";
    % the test string will include two matches
    str = "qwer12" + str1 + "09uiop" + str2;
    
    % Method 1: use strfind() with the pattern
    %  Finds two matches and returns the start index(es) in the string
    strfind(str,pat)
    
    ans =
    
        15    44    
        
    % Method 2: use extract() with the pattern
    %  Finds two matches and returns the matching text in a string array
    extract(str,pat)
    
    ans = 
    
      2×1 string array
    
        "ab C-&*\s%%8def"
        "ab C-&*\s%%8wxyz"
```

Both methods return an empty value if there is no match, so you can test for a match using [isempty()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html). Neither method modifies the input string, so you can use them in combination.

Note that `pattern` and associated functions like `extract()` are a new-ish Matlab capability, introduced in version R2020b, so these methods do not work in earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks!. Is there a way to get the length of the matched string or the end index of the matched string?

Comment: Not with strfind(), afaik. You could use `length(char(extract(str1,pat)))` to get the length of the matched string. This returns [] if there is no match, and it fails if there are multiple matches. If you want both indexes and length, and you have the possibility of multiple matches per string, then you will need two statements.

Comment: I see. Thank you for explaining. Yes, I do have the possibility of multiple matches. Is `try`/`catch` the only way or can `extract()` output cell of multiple char vec in case of multiple matches?  Would you like to add the use of `extract()` to your answer? With only the `startIndex` alone and without the `endIndex`, the matched string isn't identified.

Comment: Done. Note that because `extract()` is a new Matlab function, it returns a string array, not a cell array of character vectors. But they are more-or-less the same to work with. And if you address the string array with `{}`, it returns a char vector ¯\_(ツ)_/¯